# Count sum of digits and blank spaces in txt file Python

Tags: python, count, sum

For this I'm to create a code that counts the number of "0" in a txt file but also the number of whites paces/blank spaces. I've completed this of much of it but i'm unsure how to count the blankspaces

```
fname=open("done.txt", 'r')
text = fname.read()
count = 0
countBlank=0
for line in text:
    for char in line:
        if char.isdigit()==True:
            if char == "0":
                count = count + 1
print sum(count+countBlank)
```

Comment: You could check `if char is in ("0", " ")` and then add to count if you don't difference at the end if it is blankspace or 0

Comment: Why have you used text.split() it has not been assigned to anything

Answer (score 4):

You can check for a space using `str.isspace`, if you only want to count "0"'s then just check for a `"0"`.

```
if char == "0": 
      zero_count += 1
elif char.isspace():
     spc_count += 1
```

If you don't want an individual count use `or`:

```
  if char == "0" or char.isspace():
       total += 1
```

Or use in:

```
   total += char in {" ","0"}
```

Or use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict:

```
from collections import Counter
with open("done.txt", 'r') as f:
     cn = Counter(f.read())
     print(cn[" "])
     print(cn["0"])
     print(cn[" "] + cn["0"])
```

Just so you know `text.split()` does nothing in your code and if you had split text then you would lose all the spaces. Also `str.isspace` will work for tabs etc.. so depending on what you have in your file will decide what you can or cannot use

Answer (score 2):

Also with [builtin sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and generators:

```
text = fname.read()
total = sum(char.isspace() or char == "0" for char in text)
zero_count = sum(char == "0" for char in text)
space_count = sum(char.isspace() for char in text)
```

Comment: I doubt he needs all three. I wanted it to be copypastable.

Comment: It can be written as  `sum(char.isspace() or char == "0" for char in fname.read() ), sum(char.isspace() for char in text )`, my point is after the first sum the file object  iterator is exhausted.

Comment: Cool, sums over booleans :)

Comment: yep either 1 or 0, True or False.

Answer (score 0):

The first way that popped into my head was:

```
with open(r'input.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = len(''.join(c for line in f for c in line if c in ('0', ' ')))
```

This creates a string consisting **only** of the characters you're looking for, then determines the length of that string.